# Solving an inequality: $\;2^{x^2} \cdot 3^x < 6$

Tags: inequality

Can you show me please how can I solve the following exercise:

$$2^{\large x^2} \cdot 3^x < 6$$
Thank you , in advance :)

Comment: well, $2^1\cdot3^1=6$.  So what does that say about the exponents in regards to your inequality?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have an idea how to solve equations (or inequalities) with unknowns in the exponent?

Comment: Since $\log t$ is a strictly increasing function for positive $t$. 
$$\begin{align}
2^{x^2} \cdot 3^x < 6 
\iff & x^2\log 2 + x\log 3 < \log 6\\
\iff & (x^2 - 1)\log 2 + (x-1)\log 3 < 0\\
\iff & (x\log 2 + \log 6)(x-1) < 0\\
\iff & -\frac{\log 6}{\log 2} < x < 1
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you, but I do not understand how did you get  (x2-1) and (x-1) in the second line?

Comment: $\log{6}=\log{(2\cdot{3})}=\log{2}+\log{3}$. Then subtract...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the logarithm of each side of the inequality, and recall the laws of exponents:  $$\log(a^b) = b\log(a), \\ \\ \log(a \cdot b) = \log a + \log b$$

---

$$\begin{align} 2^{\large x^2} \cdot 3^x < 6 & \iff \log(2^{x^2} \cdot 3^x) < \log 6 \\ \\ &\iff \log (2^{x^2}) + \log (3^x) < \log 6 \\ \\ & \iff x^2 \log(2) + x\log(3) < \log 6\\  \\& \iff x^2 \log(2) + x\log(3) - \log 6 \lt 0 \\ \\ &\iff x^2 \log(2) + x\log(3) - (\log(2\cdot 3))< 0 \\ \\ &\iff x^2 \log(2) + x\log(3) - (\log 2 + \log 3) \lt 0\end{align}$$

Clearly, you have a quadratic in $x$. Solve for when the left-hand side *equals* the right-hand side to find the endpoints of intervals to test, and determine from there the interval(s) on $x$ which satisfies the given inequality.

Answer (score 2):

I want to show how I solved this exercise, thanks to the helps I received from amWhy, Alijah Ahmed, Achille Hui, Christopher Ernst:

$\large{
\displaystyle 2^{x^2}\cdot 3^x\lt 6 \\\\
\log_ 2(2^{x^2}\cdot3^x)\lt\log_2     6\\
\log_2 2^{x^2}+\log_2 3^x\lt \log_2   6 \\
x^2+x\log_2 3\lt \log_2 6 \\
x^2+x\log_2 3-\log_2 6\lt 0\\
x\in(-\log_26, 1)}
$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: write the exponentials in the same base.

Answer (score 1):

Take the logarithm of both sides of the inequality - you will get a quadratic in the variable $x$ which you can factorise. I leave the rest to you.